# Could I use Spring EL inside bean id attribute?

Tags: spring, spring-el

Could I use SpEL inside the id attribute of a bean ?

e.g :
 `<bean id="#{T(com.om.m).PublicStaticFinalStringProperty}"...`

This way it's not working, what should I change or it's not possible ?

Comment: I think you have your answer: not possible.

Comment: @Bax I just tried out micfra's answer and I think it does not work in the sense that the bean's id is only the literals and not the output of the expression. Did you see other results? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird but possible (sample uses spring 3.1). Different versions working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       ">

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="myProps"/>

    <util:properties id="myProps" >
        <prop key="x.y.z">possible</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="testBean" class="Bean">
        <property name="value" value="weird"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="${x.y.z}" class="Bean">
        <property name="value" value="but"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="#{testBean.value}" class="Bean">
        <property name="value" value="${x.y.z}"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Bean.java

```
public class Bean implements InitializingBean {

    String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

Comment: I just tried out your code and I'm afraid it doesn't work. I had `Bean` implement `BeanNameAware` and had it also print out the value the context is passing it and the output was the spel literals and not an interpreted expression. Also I tried injecting into `#{testBean.value}` value property the `#{${x.y.z}.value}` or `#{possible.value}` values to see if spring actually knows a bean named possible (then second bean's interpreted id) but that fails the context all together.

Comment: The above code works like a charm. It would be helpful if you post your context.xml, your bean code and the version of spring you are using. Maybe as a new so post?